# How to do Wildfly 9 Unzipped deployement of WAR file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, wildfly-9

I need to deploy a war file with unzipped mode like i need an war folder after deployment of war in same directory,How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can find out about WildFly 9 deployment at [Application Deployment](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Application+deployment).

About halfway down it shows the configuration of the `standalone.xml` deployment scanner:

```
<deployment-scanner scan-interval="5000" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" 
                    path="deployments" auto-deploy-zipped="true"
                    auto-deploy-exploded="false" />
```

The last attribute looks like the configuration item of interest.